# is it any way to pass "readonly" attribute as a props to a Form component from react-jsonschema-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

im trying to change all inputs within the Form component of react-jsonschema-form library.
i saw that there is a way to send a 'disable' prop for disabling the fields- but i can not find a way to do the same with "readonly". 
any efficient & fast idea anyone??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

could I kindly ask you what you are trying to achieve?

there several options:

1. use a wrapper for the `react-jsonschema-form` component and check for any changes of the `readonly` field
2. extend the usual text input component with `readonly` property (custom field/widget)
3. use `null` in `schema` just for showing some data as a `label` or the disabled/extended text input component via `uiSchema`

please, let me know in case of any question/clarification

Comment: hey! i used the formContext of the form, and figure it out. 
THANKS!